# Is it possible to declare C# method / function while debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, reflection.emit

Let's say you envision some extension method that would transform an object in some way into something useful for debugging purposes.  One is example is a `sqlCommand.ToScript()`  extension method that would return a string of the T-SQL script version of what it is about execute (it would declare parameters at the top of the script etc.) You'd like that extension method (or at least some function / method) to be available while debugging, but you don't want to actually define it in your code base as it would feel like clutter to the team.

I don't think Immediate Window can define functions, can it?  There is the C# Interactive Window, but can that interact with the currently executing stack after I hit a breakpoint?

I've heard Reflection.Emit() can add new code at run time.  Can I use that somehow?

Comment: [#if DEBUG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei --  that would still have to clutter up my code base though.  I want to keep the actual code somewhere else and just "plop it in" while debugging.

Comment: Then you can group the debug methods into another parts of your class using partial classes.

Comment: Ah, partial class is a good idea to address the clutter concern.  Hadn't thought of that.  Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't a partial class be just as much "clutter" as the extension method you mention in your question?

Comment: @BradleyUffner: It would be cleverly tucked away in a different class declaration.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So would the extension method.

Comment: What extension method?  That seems a bit far afield.

Comment: @RobertHarvey He mentions that he could do this using extension methods in the question, but says that would introduce clutter.

Comment: Actually I forgot that an extension method goes in a separate static class that could be tucked away somewhere , out of view.   My original concern was cluttering up an existing class definition.  However, the best in my mind would be if you didn't have to make any changes to your solution at all to get it to work

Comment: @unnknown You can also make it a bit better, by putting the codes into another assembly and add reference them conditionally. See the example.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, Nice.  I didn't even know references could be conditional

Comment: So you may want to take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2019) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch?view=vs-2019) like later.

Comment: And the 3rd solution, loading `Assembly` in immediate window and using your extension methods from an external assembly without adding reference.

Comment: There's also possibility of extending the immediate window or creating a new window for debug which allows you to use your debug tool set (including extension methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from extending Immediate Window or creating new extension for VS, I can think of the following solutions to let you have some debug methods:

- Using #if DEBUG + Partial Classes or Extension Methods
- Using Conditional Reference + Extension Methods
- Using Assembly.Load in Immediate Window + Extension Methods

I'll share example for each of the above solutions.

#### Using #if DEBUG + Partial Classes or Extension Methods

You can use [#if DEBUG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if). For types in your code base, you can group the debug methods into another parts of your class using partial classes, like this:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
#if DEBUG
    public string SaySomething()
    {
        return "Something!";
    }
#endif 
}
```

For types which doesn't belong to you , you can use extension methods like this (You can also use this solution for the types which belongs to you):

```
public static class SqlCommandExtensions
{
#if DEBUG
    public static string SaySomething(this SqlCommand command)
    {
        return "Something!";
    }
#endif
}
```

#### Using Conditional Reference + Extension Methods

If you would like to put all these code in a different library, you car create a class library and put the extension classes in global namespace (no namespace) and then add a conditional reference:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <Reference Include="GlobalExtensions">
    <HintPath>..\Somewhere\GlobalExtensions.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

In this solution, you don't need if debug.

```
public static class SqlCommandExtensions
{
    public static string SaySomething(this SqlCommand command)
    {
        return "Something!";
    }
}
```

#### Using Assembly.Load in Immediate Window + Extension Methods

As another option, you can create another assembly and then put these extension methods in global namespace (no namespace) in that assembly. Then without adding reference, and just at debug time, in the immediate window you can use them:

```
Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Somewhere\GlobalExtensions.dll")
yourSqlCommand.SaySomething()
```

In this solution, you don't need if debug, you also don't need any add reference and it's only available at debug time and immediate window:

```
public static class SqlCommandExtensions
{
    public static string SaySomething(this SqlCommand command)
    {
        return "Something!";
    }
}
```

You will not have intellisense for it in immediate Window, but it works.

Comment: I don't think that addresses his "clutter" concerns, though it depends on exactly what he means by "clutter".

Comment: @BradleyUffner maybe "clutter" is a bit opinion based because OP can group the debug methods into another parts of the class using partial classes, and it's not "clutter" IMO.

Comment: These are good points.  Still am curious if it's possible to to inject code after I hit a breakpoint though

Comment: You can add code after hitting a breakpoint but that means you'll be adding and removing code manually each time you debug.

Comment: I'm also thinking this solution wouldn't be useable in the specific example used by OP of adding a method to `SqlCommand`, since you can only create partial classes for classes that you "own".

Comment: @BradleyUffner Why? In that case it would be an extension method to SqlCommand.

Comment: An extension method is different than a partial class.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I think OP knows the differences.

Comment: All I'm saying is that your answer doesn't address the example given in OP's question, because he is specifically asking about adding a method to `SqlCommand`, which can not be done with a partial class.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I think you couldn't get the point of my answer, I added another example to make it clearer. In fact the whole point of the answer and it's whole power is in #if DEBUG. Then you can use partial classes, or extension methods or whatever you like.